# Get filtered type from a tuple

Tags: typescript

I have a tuple which contains couple of objects.

```
const repos = [
  { name: 'react', type: 'JS' },
  { name: 'angular', type: 'TS' },
] as const

const RepoTypes = typeof repos

const jsRepoTypes = FilterRepos<'JS'> // Should return the type object containing only JS
```

I am looking for some generic Utility Type ( `FilterRepos<T>` ) where I can pass the `type` parameter and it should return me the filtered tuple type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use a tail-recursive type to construct a tuple by filtering out non-matching tuple elements.

```
type FilterRepos<
  T extends string, 
  REPOS extends readonly any[] = typeof repos
> = 
  REPOS extends readonly [infer L, ...infer R] 
    ? L extends { type: T } 
      ? [L, ...FilterRepos<T, R>] 
      : FilterRepos<T, R>
    : []

type JsRepoTypes = FilterRepos<'JS'>
// type JsRepoTypes = [{
//     readonly name: "react";
//     readonly type: "JS";
// }, {
//     readonly name: "vue";
//     readonly type: "JS";
// }]
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=25&ssc=6&pln=8&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBATgUwA4gjAvDA2gKBjAbxjAEMBbBALhgHJETgoaAaGKATyStoCkBlGjAC+zPIWLluNAG4BXBCzacp-QSLFFSFajRJgA5rIA2JOIo5cdAFQHDRAXRgk0oSFBweLCGADEAlkZQCHAASsioADxiVjAIAB5BYAAmaNBwfgasYiEAogAKAPJ8sQkIyWj0SeBG7E5g7FiOmF4gAGbw4RA4AHwYMNn5RSWJKR0kVWA12BmtwTAAMqwAdCszcyGOYvgA-AvDZaNEXtQxQv34FzC7WIswK0v+gcFhKBARVqwh3ZuX+NSPQVCnXen26Wxg1EanmUMB4EBeICsyjQmABz2BNFUYIA9NilFxYfDwkiuCjsAQcLjfpVqrUtNwAET0RgMgDclLxlxpk1qxxgDP4bI5dkIwq5CHGtIk2n5cgQQqp4slPPxjMF7KpQnsQA)

Comment: This is great!  Is there anyway to convert the final Union type to Tuple type?

Comment: @HemandS - oof, that makes things more complicated. See the edit.